# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

i got the error like Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.but i import FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule and declared in imports but i got same error please any one help me thanks
 my code is :

```
          <form  [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="login()"  class="md-form-auth form-validation"  (keypress)="keyDownFunction($event)">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <md-input-container class="full-width md-icon-left">
                            <md-icon class="material-icons">mail_outline</md-icon>
                            <input  mdInput type="email" placeholder="Email"
                                   formControlName="Username">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <md-input-container class="full-width md-icon-left">
                            <md-icon class="material-icons">lock_outline</md-icon>
                            <input  mdInput type="password"  placeholder="Password"
                                    formControlName="Password">
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>

                    <button  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"  md-raised-button type="button" color="primary" class="float-right">
                        Login
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: how does your component look like?

Comment: Do you import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in the correct module? Please create a _minimal_ reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't created `loginForm` formgroup in component.

You can create it with following code. Copy this code in your login Component and error will vanish.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit { private loginForm : FormGroup;
    loading:boolean = false;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            Username: ['',  [Validators.required]],
            Password: ['',[Validators.required]]
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about FormsModule, that's for template driven forms, you're making use of model driven forms, which make use of the ReactiveFormsModule. That error is thrown when you fail to import that module and try to use the [formGroup] property binding. Sometimes I import the module, but forget to actually add it to the imports array. You clearly haven't added the ReactiveFormsModule to the imports array of whichever module this component is declared in. Just check again and add it to the imports and it'll solve your problem.